# Glassfish 4.1 - JSON webservice with EclipseLink and MOXy: @EmbeddedId duplication troubles

Tags: json, moxy, glassfish-4.1

I use **GlassFish 4.1** (NetBeans), EclipseLink and the default MOXy json binding.

I have an entity with a composite primary key. I need a *flat json structure* for both input and output. It seems straight-forward, but...

If I do nothing special, I get a flatten json when marshalling, but **the unmarshalling does not work** (key = null).

If I add the annotation `@XmlPath(".")`, then it is the opposite: the unmarshalling works, but the key fields are **duplicated** in the json.

Also, MOXy seems the add a `type` field in the json, which I never asked.

Entity classes:

The PK:

```
@Embeddable
public class SensorPk implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "sensor_id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "sensor_address")
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 10)
    private String address = ADDRESS_DEFAULT;

    // + getter/setters
}
```

The entity: 
(the `@org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath` is commented)

```
@Entity
@XmlElement
@Table(name = "sensors")
public class Sensor implements Serializable{

    @EmbeddedId
    // @XmlPath(".")
    private SensorPk composedId;

    @Column(name = "sensor_name")
    @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
    private String name;

    // + getter/setters
}
```

The application configuration:

```
@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("api")
public class ApplicationConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public ApplicationConfig() {
        packages("ch.derlin.glf.bbdata");
    }
}
```

I also tried to install `jackson` (1.X and 2.X), but impossible to make it work on glassfish 4.

The output without any annotation:

XML:

```
<sensors>
   <sensor>
      <address>noaddress</address>
      <id>24</id>
      <name>TEST</name>
   </sensor>
</sensors>
```

JSON:

```
[
    {  
       "type":"sensor",
       "address":"noaddress",
       "id":24,
       "name":"TEST MONNEY"
    }
]
```

Nice, but the unmarshalling of the same json fails: id and address are null. And also, *what the hell is this type field* ?

With annotation:

XML: idem.

JSON:

```
[
    {  
       "type":"sensor",
       "address":"noaddress",
       "id":24,
       "address":"noaddress",
       "id":24,
       "name":"TEST MONNEY"
    }
]
```

But the unmarshalling works properly.

Any idea guys ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, for those with the same problem, I finally made it work be replacing `@EmbeddedId` with `@IdClass`.

The class `SensorPk` is left untouched, but the `Sensor` class is rewritten like this:

```
@IdClass(SensorPk.class)
public class Sensor implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "sensor_id")
    @Id private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "sensor_address")
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 10)
    @Id private String address = ADDRESS_DEFAULT;

    @Column(name = "sensor_name")
    @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
    private String name;
}
```

Changes are:

- the annotation `@IdClass` is added at the top,
- the `SensorPk` fields are copy pasted with the annotation `@Id`